# jQuery form not being submitted. Firebug no errors

Tags: jquery

This jQuery isn't working.  When i click Vote nothing happens.  The div ratecontainer should disappear and nothing is inserted into MySQL when i check.  In Firebug i get no errors.  What did i do wrong?

```
echo "<div class='ratecontainer'>   
<form id='rateform' action=''>  
<input type='hidden' id='rateid' value='$stackid' />
<input type='hidden' id='type' value='1' />     
<a class='vote'>Vote</a>
</form>
</div>";

 $(function() {
$('.vote').click(function() {


    var rate= $("#rateid").val();  
    var type= $("#type").val(); 
    var vote = "0";    
    var dataString = 'id=' + rate + '&type=' + type + '&v=' + vote;

      //alert (dataString);return false;
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/rate.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function() {

          $('.ratecontainer').hide();

         }
      });
      return false;

});

});
```

Comment: Why do you echo the whole markup? Where is the code of your rate.php? Have you tried alerting or logging variables during the execution of the script?

Comment: Check what's in dataString...

Comment: how do i alert in jQuery?  is it alert("test");

Comment: Sure... but `console.log('string')` is better.

Comment: ok i added alert("test"); just inside the click function.  When i click the button nothing happens?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your jquery code is inside

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 </script>
```

?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see it right away. But I know there is a really nice jQuery plugin to make this easier for you: http://jquery.malsup.com/form/

You should have rate.php do some debugging... for example `print_r($_POST);`

Answer (score 0):

Your code should probably be like this:

```
<div class='ratecontainer'>   
    <form id='rateform' action=''>  
        <input type='hidden' id='rateid' value='<?php echo $stackid ?>' />
        <input type='hidden' id='type' value='1' />     
        <a class='vote'>Vote</a>
    </form>
</div>

<script>
$(function() {
  $('.vote').click(function() {


    var rate= $("#rateid").val();  
    var type= $("#type").val(); 
    var vote = "0";    
    var dataString = 'id=' + rate + '&type=' + type + '&v=' + vote;

     //alert (dataString);return false;
     $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "/rate.php",
       data: dataString,
       success: function() {

         $('.ratecontainer').hide();

        }
      });
      return false;

  });

});
</script>
```

And **don't** have that wrapped in a big `<?php ?>` tag. Assuming your `rate.php` is written correctly (which is a stretch) this should work. ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EWDu4/2/))